# Plotting 2 variables of different sizes with geom_line

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, facet-wrap

I am trying to plot on a facet_wrap using geom_line two different variables of different sizes (the second one has a lot of *NA*) but using the same x axis (Years). Unfortunately the lines plots only for the biggest variable. How can I do it?

Here is an example of the format of my data, and my simplified code:

| Sector | Scenario | Year | Emissions1 | Emissions2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Buildings | S1 | 2019 | 65 | *NA* |
| Buildings | S1 | 2020 | 45 | 75 |
| Buildings | S2 | 2021 | 25 | *NA* |
| Buildings | S2 | 2022 | 67 | *NA* |
| Transport | S1 | 2019 | 86 | 65 |
| Transport | S1 | 2020 | 86 | 59 |
| Transport | S2 | 2021 | 68 | *NA* |
| ..... | ..... | ..... | ..... | ..... |

```
Title <- paste("World total GHG emissions, exc. LULUCF, all scenarios")
Subheader <- paste("Subheader ")


(Plot <- FinalTableAverage %>%
   filter(Sector == 'Transport') %>%
   select(-Sector) %>%
   pivot_longer(c(4:last_col()), names_to = 'Model', values_to = 'Value') %>%
   ggplot(aes(x = as.numeric(Year), y = Value, color = Model )) +
   geom_line(size=1) +
   geom_point(size=1.5) +
   ggtitle(Title , subtitle = Subheader )  +
   theme_bw() +
   facet_wrap(~ Scenario, scale = "free")+
   theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
         plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 15),
         plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 10),
         legend.position = "bottom",
         legend.title = element_blank())
)
```

Comment: Hi, @Olivier. Can you please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/6288065) of your data? E.g., you can provide the output from `dput(FinalTableAverage)` or (preferably) a modified subset version to keep the data minimal. From the looks of you data right now, you don't have any complete 2-time-point "Emissions2" Models within the "S2" Scenarios. I suggest that you filter out those incomplete data pairs before sharing the example data.

Answer (score 0):

While it is a bit difficult to see without your source data, you can do something like this:

```
FinalTableAverage %>% 
  filter(Sector == 'Transport') %>%
  select(-Sector) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Emissions"), names_to = 'Model', values_to = 'Value') %>%
  filter(!is.na(Value)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = as.numeric(Year), y = Value, color = Model )) +
  geom_line(size=1) +
  geom_point(size=1.5) +
  ggtitle(Title, subtitle = Subheader )  +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(~ Scenario, scale = "free")+
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 15),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 10),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.title = element_blank())
)
```

Output:

[image: facet_plot]

Input:

```
structure(list(Sector = c("Buildings", "Buildings", "Buildings", 
"Buildings", "Transport", "Transport", "Transport", "Transport", 
"Transport", "Transport", "Transport", "Transport"), Scenario = c("S1", 
"S1", "S2", "S2", "S1", "S1", "S1", "S1", "S2", "S2", "S2", "S2"
), Year = c(2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2019, 
2020, 2021, 2022), Emissions1 = c(65L, 45L, 25L, 67L, 86L, 86L, 
48L, 50L, 48L, 48L, 68L, 43L), Emissions2 = c(NA, 75L, NA, NA, 
65L, 59L, 88L, 66L, 86L, 61L, NA, 72L)), row.names = c(NA, -12L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I feel stupid but this is exactly what I needed, thank you so much!